# Events on elements in Relative Layout not firing

Tags: xaml, xamarin, button, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms and events on elements inside of a relative layout are not firing.  I tried to register them in code behind as well and still not firing.  I have -250 constraint on it because buttons were showing up on the bottom of the screen and it was the only way I could move them up.
Here is my xaml:

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <RelativeLayout>
        <Grid Margin="0,0,10,0"
              x:Name="grid"
              RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=10}" 
              RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=0}" 
              >


        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="0"
                Text="IP Address"
               Margin="10,10,0,0"
               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        <Entry Grid.Column="1"  
               Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="IPAddress"
            Placeholder="IP"
               WidthRequest="200"

                Margin="0,0,10,0"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="1"
                Text="Port"
               Margin="10,10,0,0"
               MinimumWidthRequest="100"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
        <Entry Grid.Column="1"  
               Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="Port"
               Margin="0,0,10,0"
            Placeholder="Port"
                WidthRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="2"
               Margin="10,10,0,0"
                Text="User Name"
               MinimumWidthRequest="100"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
        <Entry Grid.Column="1"  
               Grid.Row="2"
            x:Name="UserName"
               Margin="0,0,10,0"
                WidthRequest="200"
            Placeholder="User Name"
            HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="3"
               Margin="10,10,0,0"
                Text="Password"
               MinimumWidthRequest="100"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
        <Entry Grid.Column="1"  
               Grid.Row="3"
            x:Name="Password"
               IsPassword="True"
               Margin="0,0,10,0"
                WidthRequest="200"
            Placeholder="Password"
            HorizontalOptions="End"/>

        </Grid>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        IsEnabled="True">
        <Button x:Name="SaveBtn"
                IsEnabled="True"
                WidthRequest="100"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=-250}"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=30}"
                Clicked="SaveBtn_Clicked"
                BorderColor="Gray"
                Text="Save"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="ClearFavorites"
                IsEnabled="True"
                WidthRequest="120"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=-250}" 
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5, Constant=20}"
                Clicked="ClearFavorites_Clicked"
                BorderColor="Gray"
                Text="Clear Favorites"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: show your code with SaveBtn_Clicked defined

Comment: your constraints are taking buttons out of screen. When I set them to see buttons I get both click events

Comment: What device are you using?  I am testing on 5s and 6, and the buttons are on the screen.

Comment: Android simulator 5# marsmallow. How Y Constant=-250 can be on screen?

Comment: The buttons were showing up at the very bottom of my screen.  Adding -250 constraint was only way I could move them vertically.

Comment: did you edit your question? This is much bigger than I saw before

Comment: Yes I did, sorry thought I typed that in last comment..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147744/discussion-between-jp-hochbaum-and-yuri-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion on chat this seems to work

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"> 
<RelativeLayout> 
<Grid Margin="0,0,10,0" 
x:Name="grid" 
RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=10}" 
RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=0}" 
> 


<Grid.RowDefinitions> 
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> 
</Grid.RowDefinitions> 
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
<ColumnDefinition Width="50*" /> 
<ColumnDefinition Width="50*" /> 
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 

<Label Grid.Column="0" 
Grid.Row="0" 
Text="IP Address" 
Margin="10,10,0,0" 
HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/> 
<Entry Grid.Column="1" 
Grid.Row="0" 
x:Name="IPAddress" 
Placeholder="IP" 
WidthRequest="200" 

Margin="0,0,10,0" 
HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/> 
<Label Grid.Column="0" 
Grid.Row="1" 
Text="Port" 
Margin="10,10,0,0" 
MinimumWidthRequest="100" 
HorizontalOptions="Start"/> 
<Entry Grid.Column="1" 
Grid.Row="1" 
x:Name="Port" 
Margin="0,0,10,0" 
Placeholder="Port" 
WidthRequest="200" 
HorizontalOptions="End"/> 
<Label Grid.Column="0" 
Grid.Row="2" 
Margin="10,10,0,0" 
Text="User Name" 
MinimumWidthRequest="100" 
HorizontalOptions="Start"/> 
<Entry Grid.Column="1" 
Grid.Row="2" 
x:Name="UserName" 
Margin="0,0,10,0" 
WidthRequest="200" 
Placeholder="User Name" 
HorizontalOptions="End"/> 
<Label Grid.Column="0" 
Grid.Row="3" 
Margin="10,10,0,0" 
Text="Password" 
MinimumWidthRequest="100" 
HorizontalOptions="Start"/> 
<Entry Grid.Column="1" 
Grid.Row="3" 
x:Name="Password" 
IsPassword="True" 
Margin="0,0,10,0" 
WidthRequest="200" 
Placeholder="Password" 
HorizontalOptions="End"/> 

</Grid> 

</RelativeLayout> 
<RelativeLayout 
IsEnabled="True"> 
<Button x:Name="SaveBtn" 
IsEnabled="True" 
WidthRequest="100" 
RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=50}" 
RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=30}" 
Clicked="SaveBtn_Clicked" 
BorderColor="Gray" 
Text="Save"></Button> 
<Button x:Name="ClearFavorites" 
IsEnabled="True" 
WidthRequest="120" 
RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=50}" 
RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5, Constant=20}" 
Clicked="ClearFavorites_Clicked" 
BorderColor="Gray" 
Text="Clear Favorites"></Button> 
</RelativeLayout> 
</StackLayout>
```